# Angular HttpClient Post error Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

Tags: angular, rest

In my angular app I do a post request as shown below.

```
this.http.post('http://13.229.115.110:8080/orders', {
  'price': 17,
  'quantity': 1,
  'owner': 'OwnerOne'
}).subscribe(data => console.log('data recived ', data), error => console.log('error', error));
```

But I get the below error

```
OPTIONS http://13.229.115.110:8080/orders 403 (Forbidden)
Failed to load http://13.229.115.110:8080/orders: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403.
```

I have no access to change the server code/configurations. How do I solve this issue? Note: I have enabled cross-origin resource sharing in my chrome browser

Comment: In the code above the this.http is a HttpClient

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot solve this without changing server code.